# Delay differential equation in MATLAB (dde23 )

Tags: matlab, delay, differential-equations, dde

I've been trying to create a biological model with weekly drug injections that causes few of the immune cells types to react only 7-14 days .The model consists of a for loop  with index of the number of weeks, and lags array for the delays.
However, if I change delay of  7 days to 14 days I get the same solution.
Is there any problem with my code?
would really appreciate if you have any idea how to fix it.

```
%paramaters and delay
a=6;
b=10;
c=9;
lags = [7 ];

y0 = [ 200 9.5*5*10^3 0.5*5*10^3 10^3 100 100];
tspan =[0,6/24];
n_weeks =6;
opt = odeset('AbsTol',1e-9,'RelTol',1e-6);

%Modeling 3 injections
for i=1:3
  
sol =dde23(@(t,y,Z)ddefun(t,y,Z,a,b,c),lags,y0,tspan,opt);
semilogy(sol.x,sol.y(1,:),'r',sol.x,sol.y(2,:),'k',sol.x,sol.y(3,:),'b',sol.x,sol.y(4,:),'m',sol.x,sol.y(5,:),'g',sol.x,sol.y(6,:),'y')
legend('1','2','3','4','5','6')
xlabel('Time t');
ylabel('Solution y');
hold on

y0=sol.y(:,end);
tspan = [7*(i-1)+6/24,7*(i-1)+22/24];
m1=0;
sol =dde23(@(t,y,Z)ddefun(t,y,Z,a,b,c),lags,y0,tspan,opt);
semilogy(sol.x,sol.y(1,:),'r',sol.x,sol.y(2,:),'k',sol.x,sol.y(3,:),'b',sol.x,sol.y(4,:),'m',sol.x,sol.y(5,:),'g',sol.x,sol.y(6,:),'y')
legend('1','2','3','4','5','6')
xlabel('Time t');
ylabel('Solution y');
hold on

y0=sol.y(:,end);
mu1=0;
m1=0;
tspan = [7*(i-1)+22/24,7*i];
sol =dde23(@(t,y,Z)ddefun(t,y,Z,a,b,c),lags,y0,tspan,opt);
semilogy(sol.x,sol.y(1,:),'r',sol.x,sol.y(2,:),'k',sol.x,sol.y(3,:),'b',sol.x,sol.y(4,:),'m',sol.x,sol.y(5,:),'g',sol.x,sol.y(6,:),'y')
legend('1','2','3','4','5','6')
xlabel('Time t');
ylabel('Solution y');
hold on

y0=sol.y(:,end);
tspan = [7*i,7*i+6/24];
end


hold off
%-------------------------------------------
function dydt = ddefun(t,y,Z,a,b,c) %equation being solved
 ylag1 = Z(:,1);

 dydt = [ a*y(1);
b*ylag1(2)*y(1);
c*y(1)+a*ylag1(3);%
y(4);
ylag1(5)*ylag1(6);
y(6)];%

end
```

[image]

Comment: What are the units for ```tspan```? You mentioned that the ```for``` loop should be over 6 weeks, but ```n_weeks``` is never used in the code...  I have the feeling something might be off in the way you handle the integration intervals between the injections.

Comment: Also, what are the unused variables ```mu``` and ```mu0``` supposed to do?

Comment: Finally, does the plot you posted look OK for the case with ```lags=7```? As your injection events appear to be just "stops" in the solution, why not using ```'Jumps'``` to tell the solver when the injections occur?

Comment: What really worries me the most if the magnitude of the output you get... the scale of the y-axis of your plot is insanely large...

Comment: And one last point: what do the injections do? The equations don't change.... basically, you are just stopping and resuming the integration at each injection event. Furthermore, instead of providing the solution of the previous ```tspan``` as a history, you pass only the last value of ```sol.y```...  My point is: besides the stop-start you introduce, there's no variation in the equations produced by the injections.